# How to bold table header when table header appears in a vertically merged row

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want bold the **table header**,

I use the code

`Selection.Tables.Item(1).Rows(1).Range.Bold = True`

but in the case of a table header in a vertically the merged row it isn't working.

Then I changed my code as below, but as shown in the picture there are still two cells that are not bold. Can anyone give me some help?

```
Dim i, t As table
If selection.Tables.count > 0 Then
Set t = selection.Tables.Item(1)
  For i = 1 To t.Columns.count
    t.Range.Cells(i).Range.Font.Bold = -1
  Next i
End If
```

[image]

Comment: Because of the merging, your un-bolded cells are presumably not on the first row. So you need to bold the second row as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works no matter in which column(s) the cells of the first two rows are merged vertically. It bases on how Word selects when the first cell is selected, then you hold SHIFT and extend the selection using the Right-Arrow key.

Unlike in the user interface, when the selection is extended cell-by-cell using `MoveEnd` the vertically merged cells are picked up immediately. That's why the number of moves corresponds to one less than the number of columns.

```
Sub BoldTableHeaderVertMergedCells()
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim cel As Word.Cell
    Dim sel As Word.Selection
    Dim nrCols As Long, nrCol As Long

    Set sel = Selection
    nrCol = 1
    If sel.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Set tbl = sel.Tables(1)
        nrCols = tbl.Columns.Count
        Set cel = tbl.Cell(1, 1)
        cel.Select
        Set sel = Selection
        sel.MoveEnd wdCell, nrCols - 1
        sel.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, `sel.MoveEnd wdCell, nrCols - 1` help me a lot.

Comment: My reputation is 8 now, can you vote for my question, so I can vote up for someone who helps me. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim i As Long
With Selection.Tables(1).Range
  For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
    If .Cells(i).RowIndex < 3 Then
      .Cells(i).Range.Font.Bold = True
    Else
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, `RowIndex` this demo deepens my understanding of cells